# VS 2008 Custom Tool Problem

Tags: c#

Hi
I have custom tool for Generating a Wrapper class for code that we use.
I registered the Dll (using regasm /codebase) and can see key in registry.
But VS says "cannot find custom tool on this system".
What is wrong with it ?i dont know the reason,can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Dimaka'blog : [Install Custom Tool for VS](http://www.dimaka.com/blog/post/How-to-install-the-Custom-Tool-for-Visual-Studio.aspx).

Can you confirm you took all thses steps ?

1. Run Visual Studio Command Prompt
2. Run the commands there (VisualStudio.CodeGeneration.dll – assembly with my custom tools):

   RegAsm.exe C:..full..path.here..\VisualStudio.CodeGeneration.dll /unregister

   GacUtil.exe /u VisualStudio.CodeGeneration

   RegAsm.exe C:..full..path.here..\VisualStudio.CodeGeneration.dll

   GacUtil.exe /i C:..full..path.here..\VisualStudio.CodeGeneration.dll
3. Sometimes Visual Studio requires to run ‘devenv /setup’ command to refresh IDE.

Comment: Thank you, `devenv /setup` worked. Was banging my head against the wall for a few hours...