# Suppress warning without code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, warnings, compiler-warnings

I am trying to suppress some warnings in Visual Studio, but the problem is that they don't have a code or anything I could use to identify them(or I can't find it).

Most of these errors look like "The referenced component could not be loaded" or 'cannot find custom tool on this system'.

Both these type of errors appear on the Error List tab from visual studio, but they don't appear in the Output tab, where I could see their' code also.

If anyone could give me some tips about how to suppress them, would be great.

Comment: *The referenced component could not be loaded* - check the Modules Window, Debug Menu > Windows > Modules

Comment: *custom tool...* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460399/vs-2008-custom-tool-problem

Comment: Project Properties -> Build -> Suppress warnings. Try adding the warning __text__ there.

Comment: Have you tried the [SuppressMessageAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings#use-the-suppressmessageattribute) with just the warning text?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are referenced assemblies with yellow warning signs. If your code still compiles, you can remove these.